# I am using the IDEA to develop the Spark Demo,How to set the params about spark memory size in the local mode?

Tags: apache-spark, geospark

I am running a geoSpark Demo in the local mode,not standalone.The data's size is about 5GB. And I am getting the OOM Error.The I want to change the spark memory in the local mode ,how to do it?

Comment: I use IDEA to develop spark demo

Comment: can you add the code you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

```
conf=SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
```

Comment: oh,yes.But  I want to use config file. where to put it in the maven project ?

Comment: Locally there is no such possibility.